# Jquery code doesn't work without alert

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
var countChecked = function () {
  var n = $("input:checked").length;
  $("#count").text(n + (n === 1 ? " is" : " are") + " checked!");
};

countChecked();
alert();        // this alert

$("input[type=checkbox]").on("click", countChecked);
```

I use this code to count the number of checkbox inputs that are checked.

With `alert()` this works well. But without the alert this is not working. How can i fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Only one line code is enough for your outcome:-***

```js
$( "input[type=checkbox]" ).on( "click",function(){
    alert($("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Cycle"> I have a cycle<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> I have a bike<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Auto"> I have a Auto<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car"> I have a car<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bus"> I have a bus<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Truck"> I have a truck<br>
```

Note:- your code starts processing without waiting the document to load properly so basically it need to be failed, but when `alert()` comes then it waits for document to be rendered properly, and then you code outputs the result.

Put the whole code inside `$(document).ready(function(){` and you are good to go (then you can remove `alert()`also).

But more easiest solution is given by me.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> With alert() this work well.But without alert() this is not working.How can i fix it

The code doesn't wait until the DOM is ready. [alert()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert) is a blocking event, after which the DOM is usually loaded. One way to achieve the desired functionality without the alert is by observing the [*DOMContentLoaded*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event on the DOM with [.ready()](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) (i.e. `$(document).ready()`).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var countChecked = function() {
    var n = $("input:checked").length;
    $("#count").text(n + (n === 1 ? " is" : " are") + " checked!");
  };

  countChecked();

  $("input[type=checkbox]").on("click", countChecked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Count:<span id="count"></span></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" value="1" id="one"><label for="one">1</label></div>
<div><input type="checkbox" value="2" id="two"><label for="one">2</label></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs to be enclosed with document.ready Jquery function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var countChecked = function () {
    var n = $("input:checked").length;
    $("#count").text(n + (n === 1 ? " is" : " are") + " checked!");
  };

 countChecked();
 alert();        // this alert

 $("input[type=checkbox]").on("click", countChecked);
})
```